# javascript: read packet information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ip

I am not sure if this is possible. Essentially I want to run javascript. While I am running javascript code on the client I would like to send an ajax request to my server to do some stuff and then send the information back to the client. When this is sent back I am wondering if it is possible for javascript (or jquery) to read the source ip and destination ip address that this ajax response came from?

Answer (score 1):

send that info as part of json in the response as server already knows everything.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need the client to be able to read the source and destination ip without using the server. I know this sounds very stupid, but it is because I am testing certain attacks and want to make sure the packet is coming from where it is supposed to be coming from. (Without the use of ssl)

Comment: it is definitely the server that is returning the response as you are making ajax calls to it and getting the response.

Comment: Things such as proxies can modify the packet and without going into all the detail of the project, I need to simply compare ip address to see if they have been modified and stuff. Hence, I think the reading packet information from the client would be the best way, if this is even possible?

Comment: you cannot get ip address but `request.getResponseHeaders` function will give you all the possible headers provided in the response by the server.